# How to install pre-built Pillow wheel with libraqm DLLs on Windows?

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-wheel

I tried using the pre-built wheels for `Pillow` and corresponding `libraqm` DLL from here:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)

But the following returns `False`:

```py
from PIL import features
features.check('raqm')
```

Am I missing anything?

Context: I need `libraqm` with `Pillow` to work with complex fonts on images, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936840/).

Comment: Place the 32/64-bit `libraqm.dll` and `fribidi-0.dll` next to 32/64-bit `python.exe`

Comment: Works now, I was placing it in `C:\Windows\System32` as we generally do with most DLLs. Thanks a lot, both for the help and your binaries!! :)

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who wants `RAQM` with `PIL` on Windows, just do `pip install Pillow`.

Then place the [`libraqm` DLLs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) in some directory, and then append that directory to environment/shell variable `PATH`. That's it.

Or you could place those DLLs along with your `python.exe` [as commented by @cgohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939101/how-to-install-pre-built-pillow-wheel-with-libraqm-dlls-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment111301986_62939101).

Comment: I think this should be stated somewhere officially. It's kinda hard to find this answer although the solution was simple

Comment: It won't be stated officially, because it is not an official build.

Comment: @GokulNC I did as mentioned here. Installed Pillow using pip
Took the x64 DLLs from the path and pasted them next to python.exe at C:\Python39\
But I still get "False" when I check for raqm feature. And get no text when using PIL to draw Hindi/Telugu text on images
Windows 10, Python 3.9 and Pillow 8.2.0
Can you please help?

Comment: @cvipul The 8.2.0 and 8.3.0 releases were built without Raqm support, you should upgrade to 8.3.1. See the discussion starting here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4859#issuecomment-873110296

Comment: Thanks @Nulano let me upgrade and check. I remember 8.2.0 working on linux with raqm, which the thread also says. So I assumed it would work in windows too.

Comment: placing Dlls works perfectly fine ..

Answer (score 2):

The top-voted answer by @GokulNC is now slightly outdated; Pillow 8.2.0+ no longer uses `libraqm.dll`, but instead `fribidi.dll`.

From the [installation documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#external-libraries):

> Pillow wheels since version 8.2.0 include a modified version of libraqm that loads libfribidi at runtime if it is installed. On Windows this requires compiling FriBiDi and installing `fribidi.dll` into a directory listed in the [Dynamic-link library search order (Microsoft Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps) (`fribidi-0.dll` or `libfribidi-0.dll` are also detected). [...]

So, to use Raqm on Windows with the precompiled wheels (i.e. after running `python.exe -m pip install Pillow`), you now need to place `fribidi.dll` in any of the [searched directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps); I usually use the Python install directory, i.e. where `python.exe` is located, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python312\`.

You can download a precompiled `fribidi.dll` from the [Pillow `wheels.yml` workflow on GitHub](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/actions/workflows/wheels.yml): select a recent passing build and download and extract the correct `fribidi-...` artifact for your version of Python, x86/x64/ARM64 (you may have to log in to download artifacts).

Answer (score 1):

Just some extra information about [Gokul NC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939778/21555253).

I tried adding the folder path where I put the libraries to `PYTHONPATH` but it did not work for me. What it worked for me was adding the folder path to `PATH`.

There is an important difference between them. PYTHONPATH will be used for Python to search for modules whereas PATH will be used for Windows to dynamically load dlls.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a further data point:

@GokulNC's answer didn't work on Python 3.10 with Pillow 9.5.0 (most recent at the time of writing).

Using Python 3.7 with Pillow 8.0.0 does work as described, when adding a folder including the x64 versions of the two dlls to the PATH variable.

I'm on Windows 11.

Comment: You now need `fribidi.dll` instead of `libraqm.dll`, see my answer below.