# How to put skin-toned emojis (black thumbs up, white thumbs up) on images?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, emoji, emoji-tones

I want the output to be like this (found at GitHub):

[image: this (found from github)].

But currently I am this:

[image: getting this]

The skin tone of an emoji gets separated in my output. How do I fix this? Do I need other libraries?

The GitHub code: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4955

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def test(font, out_name):
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype(font, size=109, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM)
    im = Image.new("RGBA", (600, 600), (100, 100, 100, 100))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((0, 32), "a\u263A", fill="#faa2", embedded_color=True, font=fnt)
    draw.text((0, 132), "a\u263A", fill="#faa8", embedded_color=True, font=fnt)
    draw.text((0, 232), "a\u263A", fill="#faa", embedded_color=True, font=fnt)
    draw.text((0, 332), "\U0001F3AC\U0001F44B\U0001F3FB\U0001F44B\U0001F3FF", fill="white", embedded_color=True, font=fnt)
    draw.text((0, 432), "a\u263A", fill="#faa2", font=fnt)
    im.show()
    im.save(f"testemoji_{out_name}.png")

test(r"C:\Users\Nulano\Downloads\NotoColorEmoji.ttf", "cbdt")
test("seguiemj.ttf", "colr")
```

My code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
 
def test(font, out_name):
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype(font, size=109, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_BASIC,encoding='utf-16')
    im = Image.new("RGBA", (800, 600), (100, 100, 100, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((0, 32), "a\u263A",font=fnt, fill="#faa2", embedded_color=True)
    draw.text((0, 132), "a\u263A",font=fnt, fill="#faa8", embedded_color=True)
    draw.text((0, 232), "a\u263A", fill="#faa",font=fnt, embedded_color=True)
    draw.text((0, 332), "\U0001F3AC\U0001F44B\U0001F3FB\U0001F44B\U0001F3FF",font=fnt, fill="white", embedded_color=True)
    draw.text((0, 432), "a\u263A",font=fnt, fill="#faa2", embedded_color=True)
    im.save(path+"testemoji_{out_name}.png")  
    return im
     
# test(path+"Roboto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf", "cbdt")
test(path+"Roboto/seguiemj.ttf", "colr")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the original code uses

```py
fnt = ImageFont.truetype(font, size=109, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM)
```

whereas you changed the `layout_engine` parameter:

```py
fnt = ImageFont.truetype(font, size=109, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_BASIC, encoding='utf-16')
```

So, it seems you need the [Raqm](https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm) library to get advanced text layouting needed for applying those [Fitzpatrick Emoji modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Skin_color).

Now, you also seem to use the [Windows](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#windows-installation) version of Pillow, for which Raqm is not included by default. Check that by running:

```py
print(PIL.features.check_feature('raqm'))
```

Initially, I got `False` as output.

Getting pre-built Windows libraries of `libraqm` doesn't seem to be that easy, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62939101/11089932), but following the hints from the comments and answer there, you should be able to get Raqm running under some Windows 10 environment.

After following these hints, the output of the above test changed to `True` on my machine, and the given, **original(!)** code does now reproduce the linked images.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```